# React horizontal scrolling menu taking extra space from left arrow to item1

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I am using **react-horizontal-scrolling-menu** library and below is the UI

[image]

In the image you can see that there is extra space in left arrow to item1. How to remove this extra space. This is dummy UI for your reference but i'm getting the same issue in my live project and client wants to remove this extra space. Please help.

My AppList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ScrollMenu from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';

const list = [
  { name: 'item01' },
  { name: 'item2' },
  { name: 'item3' },
  { name: 'item4' },
  { name: 'item5' },
  { name: 'item6' },
  { name: 'item7' },
  { name: 'item8' },
  { name: 'item9' }
  
];

// One item component
// selected prop will be passed
const MenuItem = ({text, selected}) => {
  return <div
    className={`menu-item ${selected ? 'active' : ''}`}
    >{text}</div>;
};

// All items component
// Important! add unique key
export const Menu = (list, selected) =>
  list.map(el => {
    const {name} = el;
 
    return <MenuItem text={name} key={name} selected={selected} />;
  });

  const Arrow = ({ text, className }) => {
    return (
      <div
        className={className}
      >{text}</div>
    );
  };

const ArrowLeft = Arrow({ text: '<', className: 'arrow-prev' });
const ArrowRight = Arrow({ text: '>', className: 'arrow-next' });
 
const selected = 'item1';
 
class AppList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // call it again if items count changes
    this.menuItems = Menu(list, selected);
  }
 
  state = {
    selected
  };
 
  onSelect = key => {
    this.setState({ selected: key });
  }
 
 
  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    // Create menu from items
    const menu = this.menuItems;
 
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ScrollMenu
          data={menu}
          arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
          arrowRight={ArrowRight}
          selected={selected}
          onSelect={() =>{this.onSelect()}}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppList;
```

My App.css

```
.menu-item {
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 1px 10px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.menu-item-wrapper.active {
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
.menu-item.active {
  border: 1px green solid;
}
 
.scroll-menu-arrow {
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import AppList from './AppList'

function App() {
return (
    <div>
   <AppList></AppList>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer.

By default, alignCenter is true. I changed it to false and space is removed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

could you please show your DOM ?

I think your menu is like a list with ul tag and then li tag.
As default, the ul tag has a margin-left

You can do that :

```
ul{
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added the main App.js.